# Angularjs is based on which design pattern?, learning that one design pattern is enough?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

I am learning angular by my own, and able to understand how to code in angular. but I feel, just learning the concepts of angularjs and coding/tweeking some thing to solve the problem is not good. From now on, i would like to code effective and standardized. Frankly speaking  till now i have just concentrated on solving the problem, never concentrated on design pattern.

Do learning design pattern **WILL HELP in better problem solving**. If so there are many design patterns in javascript, if you take a look at the "Table Of Contents" in

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

learning all those patterns are important? or **is there only selected patterns that angular follows.**, Please help me if you know a better link or reference to learn angularjs.

Note: *I know there are many similar questions avaliable in web, But i want to know my understanding, so please read and understand my problem before just giving any comments*

Comment: Yes, knowing all these patterns is definitely helpful to be a good JS programmer. Yet, not all of them will apply to your application, and angular does have its own patterns (or pattern variations) anyway.

Answer (score 7):

[Igor Minar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688293/igor-minar), co-lead of the AngularJS project, said in [this post](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

> I hereby declare AngularJS to be MVW framework - Model-View-Whatever. Where Whatever stands for "whatever works for you".

This is the base (composite) pattern that AngularJS is built on. But there are many patterns used when building an Angular application:

- $watch expression: [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
- $emit, $broadcast: [Pub/Sub pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)
- [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
- directives that enhance an existing element: [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
- a parent directive with sub directives (using the `require` attribute) : [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)
- ...

I believe there is a lot of value in studying these general programming patterns because they are so widely applicable. Learn to use them, but don't apply them just to apply them.

Next to that, every AngularJS application is a JavaScript application. Therefore, it is useful to study JavaScript specific patterns such as:

- [Constructor](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) - every [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) you write is a constructor function
- [Module](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) - every service you write is a module. In the example Addy Osmani uses [an immediatly invoked anonymous function](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), while an AngularJS function is an anonymous function that later gets invoked by Angular with the right arguments.
- ...